# android Parse String into double

Tags: android

I have an android Intent sending to the server the Latitude and Longitude send as string like this

```
try {
    Double X = loc.getLatitude();
    z = Double.toString(X); 
    Double Y = loc.getLongitude();
    z2 = Double.toString(Y);

    outToServer.writeBytes(z); 
    outToServer.writeBytes(z2);
}
catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

then the latitude and longitude send and save in the server databases than other intent what to fetch the database and get this string to be able to change it to double

```
String x=inFromServer.readLine();
String y=inFromServer.readLine();

x = x.trim();
Double p1 = Double.parseDouble( x);
y = y.trim();
Double p2 = Double.parseDouble( y);
```

But it force close Despite when I use the same command to convert the string s="12.23" nothing happened—no force close.
How can I solve this problem, putting in consideration when Send the latitude and longitude as double they send as unknown symbols?

Comment: `Log` the double value to see what it is.  If it is a real double then it won't fail.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote the bytes to the stream, you didn't write them as two lines. You wrote them as two sequences of bytes. Then when you're reading them, you're reading two lines. What if there is no newline? Another thing, is you probably don't need to convert those to strings. You should be able to send the values over the stream as their binary representations. You should understand the difference between host and network byte order, as well, but I am actually not super sure how it pertains to java.

Why not use a data interchange format like JSON if you're going to send them over as strings?

Anyway, the cheap way to fix this would be to tack a newline on to the end of each of your Double.toString() lines, so when you read the data on the other side you get one double on each line, instead of having your second line come up with nothing.

Comment: z =    Double.toString(X);
         String lone = ( "\n ");
 
 
  Double Y=loc.getLongitude();
 z2= Double.toString(Y);

Comment: You mean adding new line \n ?

Comment: @gfgf, since you're reading a line twice to get the values, you need to have a newline after each of them in the stream